# Kendo UI Grid Popup Editor Data Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to bind a list to the Popup Editor screen.

The object is coming back as...

```
public IEnumerable<SystemUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get the list bound to the popup editor..

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>
```

There is a property on the SystemUserRole that states whether it is selected or not.

What I want to show is a list of checkboxes with a label of SystemUserRole.RoleName and and the checked html property bound to the IsSelected property on the model.

Anybody have any clue how to do this?

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I am working on a website for my church.